# Loading angular view dynamically based on selection from dropdown

Tags: angularjs

The following is something that I'd like to accomplish with Angular but I'm not sure if it's even possible.

My form would be comprised of 3 views/templates each with it's own controller. Two views are fixed, the third view needs to by dynamically loaded based on a value selected from a dropdown in one of the fixed views. The view and controller name would be derived based on the selected value. If possible I'd like to dynamically load the javascript for the controller of the selected view as well.

I heard some rumblings about this possibly in Angular 2.0 but I'm not exactly sure how to approach it.

Any thoughts? I'm not stuck with Angular so if another framework would work better in this case please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are talking about ng-route and $routeProvider, you can have it with ng-include.
By setting ng-include as dynamic, your html will be downloaded and replace the section.

NOTE: however, ng-include does not allow to have script tag in it.
You need to go around using your own directive.

This is the example of using ng-include,
http://plnkr.co/edit/nlGVNfSpJOjIfIXxpEKc?p=preview

```
  <body ng-app ng-init="dynamic='1.html'">
    <select ng-model="dynamic">
      <option value="1.html">dynamic 1</option>
      <option value="2.html">dynamic 2</option>
      <option value="3.html">dynamic 3</option>
    </select>
    dynamic: {{dynamic}}
    <div>Fixed 1</div>
    <div>Fixed 2</div>
    <div ng-include="dynamic"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'd also like to load a corresponding javascript file with a controller, services etc. to handle the dynamic view. So for 1.html I'd need to somehow load and 1.js or something similar. I could probably just put it all in the html though at last resort.

Comment: I ended up just using ng-include. I found if I use jQuery then the script is executed without any problem. Example here, http://plnkr.co/edit/6kQYKU